# Setup Script Not Working Properly

Tags: magento2, database, setup-script, setup

I need to add attribute through a setup script.Attribute properties are working,but the frontend properties are not applied as specified in the setup script.For example, `visible_on_front` `is_html_allowed_on_front` not working.

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$entityType = 'catalog_product';
$attributeCode= 'video';

$data = array(
    'label' => 'Video',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'type'  =>  'text',     //database input type
    'visible' => true,
    'required'  =>  false,
    'comparable'=> false,
    'searchable'    => false,
    'filterable'    => false,
    'unique'    => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'    =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'apply_to'  =>  '',
    'is_configurable'   =>  false,
);

$installer->addAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode, $data);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Part of config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Video>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Video>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <video_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </video_read>
            <video_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </video_write>
            <video_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Video</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </video_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the installer does not run correctly because you are using the wrong setup class.

In your config.xml try placing the following:

```
<video_setup>
    <setup>
       <module>Company_Video</module>
        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
    </setup>
    <connection>
       <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
</video_setup>
```

Comment: Depending on the magento version I recommend to use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`